# Run 3 observables sequentially, using result from first in the last one

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

**CONTEXT**

I would like to run 3 different operations sequentially using RxSwift:

1. Fetch products
2. When products fetching is done, delete cache
3. When cache delete is done, save new cache with products from *step 1*

These are the function definitions in my services:

```
struct MyService {

  static func fetchProducts() -> Observable<[Product]> {...}
  static func deleteCache() -> Observable<Void> {...}
  static func saveCache(_ products: [Product]) -> Observable<Void> {...}

}
```

I implement that behavior usually with `flatMapLatest`.

However, I will lose the result of the 1st observable (`[Product]`) with that approach, because the operation in the middle (`deleteCache`) doesn't receive arguments and returns Void when completed.

```
struct CacheViewModel {


  static func refreshCache() -> Observable<Void> {
    return MyService.fetchProducts()
      .flatMapLatest { lostProducts in MyService.deleteCache() }
      .flatMapLatest { MyService.saveCache($0) } // Compile error*
  }
  // * Cannot convert value of type 'Void' to expected argument type '[Product]'

}
```

The compile error is absolutely fair, since the operation in the middle 'breaks' the passing chain for the first result.

**QUESTION**

What mechanism is out there to achieve this serial execution with RxSwift, accumulating results of previous operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```swift
        service
            .fetchProducts()
            .flatMap { products in
                return service
                    .deleteCache()
                    .flatMap {
                       return service
                        .saveCache(products)
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be, just to return a new Observable of type `Observable<Products>` using the static method in the Rx framework [just](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/just.html) within the second `flatMap()`, passing in the `lostProducts` you captured in the flatmap-closure, i.e.:

```
static func refreshCache() -> Observable<Void> {
    return MyService.fetchProducts()
      .flatMapLatest { lostProducts -> Observable<[Product]> in 
        MyService.deleteCache()
        return Observable.just(lostProducts)
    }
      .flatMapLatest { MyService.saveCache($0) } // No compile error
  }
```

That way you are not losing the result of the first call in the flatMap, but just pass it through after having cleared the cache.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `do(onNext:)` for deleting the cache data and then in flatMapLatest you can save the products. Optionally `SaveCache` and `DeleteCache` should return `Completable` so that you can handle error if the save or delete operation failed.

```
struct CacheViewModel {

    static func refreshCache() -> Observable<Void> {
        return MyService.fetchProducts()
            .do(onNext: { _ in
                MyService.deleteCache()
            }).flatMap { products in
                MyService.saveCache(products)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would not recommend to do it this way, since `.do(onNext: {...})` is not thread save and also this does not create a clean subsequent chain, since `myService.deleteCache()` will be called at some time on some thread and the `MyService.saveCache(products)` within the flatMap call is called immediately, introducing a possible race condition for accessing the cache, which is not what you want.